# Reachability host not reachable no matter which host I use

Tags: ios, connection, host, reachability

This case (NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
is always running from some reason.

I'm using Apple Reachability class behind the scene.
I tried to insert other hosts but no luck please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
@implementation ConnectionManager
@synthesize internetActive, hostActive;

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self) {

}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:@"NetworkReachabilityChangedNotification" object:nil];

internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[internetReachable startNotifier];

hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
[hostReachable startNotifier];



return self;
}

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)

{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
        self.internetActive = NO;

        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
        self.internetActive = YES;

        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
        self.internetActive = YES;

        break;

    }
}

NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (hostStatus)

{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
        self.hostActive = NO;

        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
        self.hostActive = YES;

        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
        self.hostActive = YES;

        break;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you connect to the internet in other apps? You do have connectivity right?

Comment: Change `[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];` to `[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];` and check.

Comment: www.google.com is correct. Using http:// never works. Found some code in the apps I work on that had http:// and never showed the host as reachable. When changed to just www.google.com the host became reachable, but only until the network went down (computer going to sleep). Thereafter, whenever the network comes up again the host is always down. Have to restart the Simulator for it to work again. I think the simulator (Xcode 6.2) has internal issues and I always have to restart the process to regain internet connectivity after wake. Always error 1005 until then. No issues on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned about `internetReachable` showing the same error, I am assuming that you are able to connect to internet and that part is working fine. For the `hostReachable` part, you can try to change it as:

Change

```
[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
```

to

```
[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: Yes you are right Internet part is working fine, anyhow I already tried with "http://" and without still same thing.
but thank you anyway.

Comment: What about `google.com` alone? Was it working then? I just checked in an earlier project I worked on and I was just using something like this only.

Comment: I tried every way I can think of, I even tried 
- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error
it return "NO" as well.. :\